# Pygame Event.key return

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard-events

Using `Python 3.3`, `Pygame 1.9`, `PygCurse`, and `Eclipse` with the `PyDev` plugin

I have a simple loop that I need to exit when the player presses enter. Using input() is not an acceptable substitute as the loop will eventually perform different actions based on which key is pressed. So essentially, I need to test for which key is pressed and then perform an action. I am currently only testing for the enter key. Here is the loop:

```
 while 1:
     event = pygame.event.poll()
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        break;
     if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN) & (event.key == pygame.K_RETURN):
         break
```

The error this returns is:

```
 if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN) & (event.key == pygame.K_RETURN):
 AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'
```

All of the examples I've seen (from http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=pygame.event.poll) use `event.key` to identify which key is being pressed so I'm either obviously missing something in the code above or there was some kind of syntax change that I missed and I'm only looking at old examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by simply changing `&` to `and`.  Python uses `and` for a logical "and" comparison.  `&` is used for a bitwise "and" comparison.

```
while 1:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
       break
    if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN) and (event.key == pygame.K_RETURN):
       break
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. You have no idea how stupid I feel spending that much time trying to fix this. I wasn't even trying to address the real problem. Thanks.